# GRE over IPSec vs L2TP over IPSEC

Tags: ipsec, gre, l2tp

Every single VPN provider offers L2TP over IPSec. What is the reason GRE over IPSec is never offered ? Is there any downfall ? It seems to be exactly the same.

Comment: There are a few reasons. It's older I do know that. I've recently dealt with this. Here's a document that helped me understand somewhat. https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/solutions/Enterprise/WAN_and_MAN/P2P_GRE_IPSec/P2P_GRE/2_p2pGRE_Phase2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found the answer a year later while I was reading about IKEv1 vs IKEv2.

L2TP/IPSec makes it possible to use a username/password, because L2TP is built on top of ppp.

With GRE, that wouldn't be possible to authenticate with a username/password.

In IKEv2, you can use a username/password directly, so there is no need for L2TP.